# Uppercase or capital letters only in sap.m.Input controller of UI5

Tags: sapui5

I'm using a [`sap.m.Input`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input) controller in my SAPUI5 application and I would like the input text in this field will be displayed with capital letters / in uppercase only. The actual value is formatted on a backend along with the data validation.

Is there any ready-to-use property to enable the uppercase mode?
I checked the [control properties](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input/controlProperties) at API Reference, but can't find something similar.

**A question extension:**
As far as I understand, the alternative solution to JS is to use a CSS property: `text-transform: uppercase;` and to attach this style to the specific `sap.m.Input` controller.

Which approach is more preferable from the performance point of view — to use a CSS-based (`text-transform`) or a JS-based (`liveChange`) technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge, the better solution is to use the CSS:

```css
.sapMInput.myCustomCSSClass .sapMInputBaseInner {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with the [`liveChange`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input/events/liveChange) event:

```html
<Input liveChange = "onLiveChange"></Input>
```

In your controller you define the function:

```js
onLiveChange: function(oEvent) {

    var input = oEvent.getSource();

    input.setValue(input.getValue().toUpperCase());
}
```

If it is to display your initial value in your Input-control, you can define a formatter which formats your String to uppercase.

Comment: I extended the question, CSS vs JS based solution. What are your thoughts, which technique is better?

Comment: CSS-based is the better solution as there is not event attached.

Comment: Well if you are typing in the input, automatically an event will be triggered. If  you want the initial input value to be displayed in capitals I think SAP suggests the use of a formatter. Though I'm not sure so your technique might be better. I'd be intrested in other people their opinion :)

Comment: `liveChange` solution has one significant side effect: every time I type a character, the typing carriage is moved to the end of the line, even if I decide to type something in the middle of the word or sentence. That's annoying UX, CSS solution has no such drawback.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a single line of code you need only to write to solve your requirement. No need for controller, just type it in view :). This approach resolves your issue through use of expressions

```html
<Input value = "{ value: '' constraints: { search: '^[A-Z]*$' } }" />
```

Use of the `search` constraint means that it will search in the input and check it against the value you set.

`'^[A-Z]*$'` means capital letters only, this is a regular expression, or regex.

To enable automatic error handling, simply add in 1line of code under the "sap.ui5" section of your manifest.json:
`"handleValidation": true,`
It will automatically render an error message to guide the user.

Another regex expression others may find useful: `'^[A-Za-z]*$'`, which means you can type only alphabetical letters, uppercase and lowercase.

Here's a useful resource on inline validation: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8

Answer (score 0):

... or you can attach a callback to the "validationSuccess" event of a input control and in the callback execute something like this:

```
var oSrc = oEvent.getSource();

if(oSrc && oSrc.setValue){
  oSrc.setValue(oSrc.getValue().toUpperCase()); 
}
```